# file transfer upload {......"http_status":0,"code":3} Phonegap

Tags: php, android, cordova

I tried following code for file upload on FTP:

```
ft.upload(imageURI.fullPath, encodeURI("URL"), win, fail, options, true);
```

It throws error like:

1. "http_status": 0, "code": 3
2. Error getting HTTP status code from connection

Answer (score 0):

The Phonegap FileTransfer Method have  **FileTransferError** (A FileTransferError object is passed to an error callback when an error occurs.)object  It has these properties Properties

1. code: One of the predefined error codes listed below. (Number)
2. source: URL to the source. (String)
3. target: URL to the target. (String)
4. http_status: HTTP status code. This attribute is only available when a response code is received from the HTTP connection. (Number)

**Error codes**

1. FileTransferError.FILE_NOT_FOUND_ERR
2. FileTransferError.INVALID_URL_ERR
3. FileTransferError.CONNECTION_ERR
4. FileTransferError.ABORT_ERR

more information check [this](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/blob/dev/doc/index.md)